# Google Analytics - Tracking metrics for webpage content using the Data Export API

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, data-export

I'm trying to write a program that will create a report of the page views within a date range for specific webpages within my site. I've been scouring the API help section, but i can't seem to find out how to get metrics for a specific page.

I think it has something with defining a specific tableID, but I've been unable to find that number.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

new version:
you can take the tableId from the query, is the number after the "p":
for example the : 14725836
www.google.com/analytics/web/#dashboard/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxp14725836/%3F_.date00%3D20111228%26_.date01%3D20111228/

old version

is the param "id" 
www.google.com/analytics/reporting/?reset=1&id=14725836&pdr=20111127-20111227